# Evaluate the complex integral $\int_C\ \frac{e^z}{(z-1)(z-2)}dz$ in $|z-1-i|<2$.

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

The integral in question is

> $$\int_C\ \frac{e^z}{(z-1)(z-2)}dz$$
>   Where $C$ is a circle with radius $2$ centered at $1+i$.

Sketch: The key idea is use partial fraction decomposition and apply cauchy integral to each summands

Attempt:

After decomposition we obtained

$\int_C \frac{e^z}{z-2}dz - \int_C \frac{e^z}{z-1}dz$

Apply Cauchy integral to each seperate integral and we obtain $2\pi i(e^2-e)$

I want to check if my attempt is correct (please point out my mistakes if I made any),

also there is a follow up question where the integral is the same, just that $C$ is a circle centered at 0 with radius 3. Using the same argument I arrived at the same answer, is that correct ?

Comment: Yes, your reasoning and your work are correct for both problems.